# Is there a way to remove an item from a jQuery objects selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if I'm using the good terms here, but this is what I want to do :

I select a bunch of items with jQuery, like `jQuery('some-items-selected-with-class-or-else');`, then I'm working on an other bunch of items (with some of them can be in the two ""bunches"") like `jQuery('some-other-items-selected-with-class-or-else');`.

My question is : **is there a way to remove some items of the second selection from the first one ?**

If it can help, I'm working on each item of the second selection with `jQuery.each()`.

This is what I want to do :

```
var selection1 = jQuery('someitems'),
    selection2 = jQuery('someotheritemswhichcanbethesameornot');

selection2.each(function() {
   // if this item has some specifications (like a specific value or else),
   // we do something on it and it does not belong in selection1 anymore
   // => can I remove it from selection1 ?
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the example?

Comment: Without seeing the HTML this is a guess, but try `$('select.class:not(".otherclass")');`

Comment: I changed the question, hopping it will be more understandable : it is not about classes :)

Comment: In this case you can use `filter()`, but it depends on your use case which is the best approach. This is why we're asking for your HTML and a specific example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 approaches to do so:

1) Narrow your selection using [`filter()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_filter.asp):

```
jQuery('select.general-class').filter('.with-only-this');
```

2) Subtract certain elements using [`not()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp):

```
jQuery('select.general-class').not('.not-you');
```